# exclusion principle / combinations problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a word game there are $26$ letter tiles, each one with a different letter. How many ways are there of choosing seven tiles so that at least two are vowels?

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers, depending on `Y` being accounted as a vowel or not.

1. Assuming that `Y` is a vowel, we have $6\cdot\binom{20}{6}$ ways to choose seven tiles such that only one of them is a vowel, and $\binom{20}{7}$ ways to choose seven tiles such that none of them is a vowel, hence the answer is given by:
   $$ \binom{26}{7}-\binom{20}{7}-6\cdot\binom{20}{6} = 347720. $$
2. Assuming that `Y` is not a vowel, we have $5\cdot\binom{21}{6}$ ways to choose seven tiles such that only one of them is a vowel, and $\binom{21}{7}$ ways to choose seven tiles such that none of them is a vowel, hence the answer is given by:
   $$ \binom{26}{7}-\binom{21}{7}-5\cdot\binom{21}{6} = 270200. $$

Comment: thank you! according to the answers in my book, they obviously don't account Y as a vowel.

Comment: And if you were playing the game in Welsh, you’d have yet another answer: `a,e,i,o,u,w`, and `y` are all considered vowels in Welsh.